# Azure Pipelines: Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.13.0/win32-x64-83_binding.node"

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Running the Azure Pipelines and unable to get it working, have checked the github link either it's not working or version not found.

Using yaml file for Azure pipelines configuration
Unable to find the agent and clean the directories

```
npm install
  
node-sass@4.13.0 install D:\a\1\s\ClientApp\node_modules\node-sass
node scripts/install.js
  
  Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.13.0/win32-x64-83_binding.node
  Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.13.0/win32-x64-83_binding.node":
```

Comment: The version in the URL is incorrect, that download is available under the `v5.0.0` releases [here](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v5.0.0/win32-x64-83_binding.node).

Comment: its picking URL automatically, I didn't choose

Comment: Do you have `"node-sass": "4.13.0"` or something similar listed in your package.json dev/dependencies?

Comment: yeah its listed 
"optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.4.1",
    "tslint": "~5.20.0"
  }

Comment: Change that to `"node-sass": "^5.0.0"` and try running your pipeline again.

Comment: yeah it's working now and deployment completed, but I'm facing issue in routing

Comment: You can post the solution to the answer. As for the routing issue. You need to open an new thread.

Answer (score 2):

Change node-sass in package.json to "node-sass":"^5.0.0" and run npm install again